# StreamingHttpResponse doesn't block other requests in wsgi but does on channels asgi

Tags: python, django, video-streaming, streaming, django-channels

Recently I wrote a django wsgi server. it has a webcam stream and at the same time handles requests like get users or save image and other stuff. in the wsgi vesion the server worked flawlessly. at the sametime that the stream was showing footage the other requests could be handled and the server wasn't blocked. but when i switched to channels asgi because i wanted the websocket feature all fell apart. when the stream started the entire server froze and not even the websocket connected. even if the websocket was connected before the stream when the stream starts nothing works.

**WSGI Version**

```
def get_stream():
   cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
   while True:
     frame, _ = cap.read()
     valid, img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
     yield(b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + img.tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')

@api_view(['GET'])
def stream():
   return StreamingHttpResponse(get_stream(), content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame')

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_users():
    ....
```

**ASGI Version**

```
def get_stream():
   cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
   while True:
     frame, _ = cap.read()
     valid, img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
     yield(b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + img.tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')

@api_view(['GET'])
def stream():
   return StreamingHttpResponse(get_stream(), content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame')

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_users():
    ....

class consumer(WebsocketConsumer):
        def connect(self):
           self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, code):
        self.close()

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        pass
```

Comment: How exactly is the new view code ASGI? It's exactly the same with the old code. Yes, you added a consumer but the view in no way interacts with it. What server do you use to run it?

Comment: @Ken4scholars
i use the development server provided by django channels
i go into the settings.py add channels as an app then add the `ASGI_APPLICATION` variable and do the config for it **asgi.py** created by django then run `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Did you get a solution @ferjif?

Comment: no unfortunately. I had no choice but to switch to sanic framework. it's async and doesn't block even when multiple streams are open. @arriff